# Python selenium explicit wait random errors in a for loop

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, error-handling, try-except

I have this list of strings:

```
list_adjusted = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOGL', 'GOOG', 'AMZN', 'TSLA', 'FB', 'BRK-B', 'BRK-A', 'NVDA', 'TSM', 'JPM', 'V', 'BABA', 'JNJ', 'UNH', 'WMT', 'HD', 'BAC', 'PG', 'MA', 'ASML', 'DIS', 'ADBE', 'NFLX', 'CRM', 'TM', 'PYPL', 'XOM', 'NKE', 'ORCL', 'TMO', 'PFE', 'KO', 'LLY', 'CSCO', 'CMCSA', 'ACN', 'ABT', 'INTC', 'MRK', 'PEP', 'VZ', 'DHR', 'CVX', 'AVGO', 'COST', 'WFC', 'NVS', 'ABBV', 'SE', 'NVO', 'SHOP', 'AZN', 'MCD', 'MS', 'T', 'UPS', 'RDS-A', 'VTI', 'SAP', 'TXN', 'RDS-B', 'INTU', 'NEE', 'LOW', 'LIN', 'BX', 'MDT', 'HON', 'PTR', 'UNP', 'SCHW', 'QCOM', 'RY', 'PM', 'AMD', 'MRNA', 'TMUS', 'SONY', 'BLK', 'C', 'NOW', 'BBL', 'UL', 'GS', 'BHP', 'RTX', 'TTE', 'TD', 'HDB', 'AXP', 'BMY', 'ISRG', 'AMT', 'TGT', 'SBUX', 'CHTR', 'SNY', 'JD', 'SQ', 'HSBC', 'BA', 'AMAT', 'AMGN', 'CVS', 'DEO', 'TEAM', 'GE', 'LFC', 'EL', 'SNAP', 'SPGI', 'IBM', 'CAT', 'ABNB', 'PDD', 'PLD', 'SNOW', 'DE', 'BUD', 'ANTM', 'GSK', 'MMM', 'RIO', 'ZTS', 'SYK', 'BKNG', 'COP', 'BP', 'INFY', 'BAM', 'ADP', 'ADI', 'CNI', 'LMT', 'USB', 'PNC', 'ENB', 'EQNR', 'MDLZ', 'UBER', 'MMC', 'TFC', 'CB', 'SHW', 'DELL', 'HCA', 'MO', 'GILD', 'ZM', 'CSX', 'GM', 'BTI', 'BNS', 'TJX', 'LRCX', 'MU', 'SNP', 'CME', 'DUK', 'MELI', 'CCI', 'ICE', 'IBN', 'MUFG', 'MCO', 'EW', 'EQIX', 'CI', 'WBK', 'WDAY', 'AON', 'ITW', 'NSC', 'BMO', 'BNTX', 'ADSK', 'BDX', 'F']
```

and these lines of code:

```
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome("D:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")
for each in list_adjusted:
    
    web_page = driver.get('https://www.sec.gov/')
    try:
        pop_up_element = '//*[@id="acsMainInvite"]/div/a[1]'
        pop_up_click = WebDriverWait(driver,2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, pop_up_element))).click()   
        search_path = '//*[@id="global-search-box"]'
        search = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, search_path)))
        search.send_keys(each)
        search_click_element = '//*[@id="global-search-form"]/fieldset/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]'
        click_search_element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, search_click_element))).click()
        try:
            fillings_element = '//*[@id="btnViewAllFilings"]'
            click_view_fillings = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, fillings_element))).click()
            date_element = '//*[@id="filingsTable"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]'
            date_element_object = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, date_element))).text
        except:
            date_element = '//*[@id="filingsTable"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]'
            date_element_object = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, date_element))).text
        
        print([each, date_element_object])    
        if date_element_object == yday:
            stocks_with_sec_fillings.append([each, date_element_object])

    except:
        search_path = '//*[@id="global-search-box"]'
        search = WebDriverWait(driver,2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, search_path)))
        search.send_keys(each)
        search_click_element = '//*[@id="global-search-form"]/fieldset/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]'
        click_search_element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, search_click_element))).click()
        try:
            fillings_element = '//*[@id="btnViewAllFilings"]'
            click_view_fillings = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, fillings_element))).click()
            date_element = '//*[@id="filingsTable"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]'
            date_element_object = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, date_element))).text
        except:
            date_element = '//*[@id="filingsTable"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]'
            date_element_object = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, date_element))).text
        
        print([each, date_element_object]) 
        if date_element_object == yday:
            stocks_with_sec_fillings.append([each, date_element_object])
```

spontaneously as the script loops through the list errors broke the code down.

Sometimes error occur at the 12th element, sometimes at 120th... There is no clear pattern and I do not know what is causing these errors as they occur randomly.

I used various explicit selenium wait commands but without any success as errors kept popping

Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-ef92bc95b643> in <module>
      8         pop_up_element = '//*[@id="acsMainInvite"]/div/a[1]'
----> 9         pop_up_click = WebDriverWait(driver,2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, pop_up_element))).click()
     10         search_path = '//*[@id="global-search-box"]'

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     81 

TimeoutException: Message: 


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

StaleElementReferenceException            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-ef92bc95b643> in <module>
     31         search.send_keys(each)
     32         search_click_element = '//*[@id="global-search-form"]/fieldset/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]'
---> 33         click_search_element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, search_click_element))).click()
     34         try:
     35             fillings_element = '//*[@id="btnViewAllFilings"]'

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in click(self)
     78     def click(self):
     79         """Clicks the element."""
---> 80         self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
     81 
     82     def submit(self):

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    631             params = {}
    632         params['id'] = self._id
--> 633         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    634 
    635     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.81)
```

Comment: Update the question with the error you are seeing.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: I think you have common problem with `.click()`in `for`-loop. Selenium doesn't give you urls as strings but as reference to object in browser memory - and when you use `click()` then browser loads new HTML and references gives access to wrong places in browser memory. Even if you use button `back` it still may have wrong references. And this shows `element is not attached to the page document`. You have to first get URLs as strings and later run `for`-loop in which you use `get(url)` instead of `click()`

Comment: I run it only once (using `Firefox`) and I can't reproduce problem. First you should see what you have in browser when you get error. Maybe problem is not `wait` but maybe you send too many reuqests and server blocks you as spamer/hacker.

Comment: or maybe your code works too fast and browser has no time to reload page - and `Wait` finds object in old HTML but when it tries to `click()` then browser has new HTML. Maybe you should wait few second directly after `get()` (using normal `time.sleep()`)